# Go code not running as expected

Tags: go

I am building a bot that parses tinder for key words. Currently doing a test which should filter out specific names. For test purposes it is supposed to match rather than pass, hence 'true' rather than 'false'.

"Ex" is an array of names declared in a JSON file called "filter.json".

The issue is that I get a "nothing matched" notification on names declared in the array, which it should match.

```
type Filter struct {
    Ex     []string
}

func containsAny(text []string, keys []string) (string, bool) {
    for _, part := range text {
        for _, key := range keys {
            if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(part), strings.ToLower(key)) {
                return key, true
            }
        }
}

    return "", false
}

func match(rec tinder.Recommendation) (string, bool) {
    if name, ok := containsAny([]string{rec.Name}, filter.Ex); ok {
        return fmt.Sprintf("ex name: %s", name), true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of `containsAny`?

Comment: we can't guess what the rest of the code does. Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @abhink No problem, I have edited the code with the containsAny func. Thanks for looking it over.

Comment: Probably gonna have to post more of your apps code. The logic in `containsArray` looks correct to me so the problem is likely upstream. Are you sure the tinder API has returned the data you were expecting? Was it unmarshalled successfully? I don't think character encoding would be an issue in Go (pretty sure it's all UTF-8 by default) but I would start thinking of things like this that may cause the contains to fail.

Comment: The [contains any](https://play.golang.org/p/pP2oTWMbWR) works